# Unable to connect to the Octopus Deploy server

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy

We have restriction on our Firewall and added a rule to allow only below range as suggested by Microsoft:

```
IP V4 ranges    IP V6 ranges
13.107.6.0/24   2620:1ec:4::/48
13.107.9.0/24   2620:1ec:a92::/48
13.107.42.0/24  2620:1ec:21::/48
13.107.43.0/24  2620:1ec:22::/48
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

But still unable to connect. Can someone please guide me what other range to allow in our firewall to let Azure Devops make a connection to OctopusDeploy Server.

Comment: Is octopus server in your premises or in cloud ?

Comment: Can you sign into  azure devops? Are you unable to connect to the Octopus Deploy server at the service connection step in azure devops?

Comment: @NirajGajjar   Octopus Server is in our premises. and we have tested the connection by allowing everything in Firewall. so definitely, its some IP apart from above mentioned ones that needs adding in our firewall that allows AzureDevops to connect.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT How can you test a connection from service connection as cant see any option that shows connection test.

Comment: Have you allowed your public IP in azure ?

Comment: @NirajGajjar can you please explain. How can we allow public IP in Azure. Never done that please guide.

Comment: @sam - as an option one could check the firewall logs for refused connections as you will know the exact timings. The blocked connections should be allowed into logs.

Comment: Added below in our Firewall after seeing what is hitting our firewall:-
      "name": "AzureConnectors.UKSouth",
      "id": "AzureConnectors.UKSouth",
      "properties": {
        "changeNumber": 2,
        "region": "uksouth",
        "platform": "Azure",
        "systemService": "AzureConnectors",
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "51.140.61.124/32",
          "51.140.74.150/32",
          "51.140.80.51/32",
          "51.140.148.0/28"
        ]

Comment: but it is random every time. Struggling to figure out what else to allow in firewall and as per company policy we cannot allow anyone

Comment: 1) To check your public IP [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/)

Also check allowed ports in your firewall option. below link may help you.
 
2) Check the [Octopus Document](https://octopus.com/docs/administration/security/exposing-octopus)